# Default gateway IP address is the same as router IP address?

Tags: networking

Do gateway and router perform the same functions?

How do they differ?

I have not yet the satisfied answer.

explain me more details..

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on Server Fault.

Comment: This is the wrong site for networking questions, but "gateway" and "router" mean the same thing as far as TCP/IP goes.

Answer (score -2):

this is a perspective question.  from the router's point of view, it is a router.  from anything else it is a. gateway to reach things on the outside